# How can I speed up iterating large list and summing values

Tags: python, performance

```py
# Generate test data
test = list(range(150))

groups = []
```

for _ in range(75_000):
groups.append(random.sample(test, 6))

Comment: Yes, use numpy and vectorize your code.

Comment: @Julien can you show me an example

Comment: You can speed it up by 6250x by removing that `for _ in range (6250)` loop.  It's doing exactly the same thing each time so there's no reason to repeat it.

Comment: @Samwise thats just there for the example there is more work done after the fact and `scores_dict` changes every loop but the slowest part is summing the values and doing the dictionary lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup variables as numpy arrays:

```
# Best version
import numpy as np
import random
from numba import jit # Kind of optional see below

# Generate test data
test = list(range(150))

groups = np.array([random.sample(test, 6) for _ in range(75_000)])

# This will change every time but just leaving the same for example
scores_dict = {i: random.uniform(0, 120) for i in range(150)}
scores = np.array(list(scores_dict.items()))
```

Here's the vectorized version using numpy's [sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
def fun1(scores, groups):
    for _ in range(6250):
        c = np.sum(np.take(scores[:, 1], groups), axis=1)
    return c

%timeit fun1(scores, groups) # Takes ~2.5 mins to run

18.6 s ± 625 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If you really want to go all out you can try using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/index.html) on top of numpy:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def fun2(scores, groups):
    for _ in range(6250):
        c = np.sum(np.take(scores[:, 1], groups), axis=1)
    return c

%timeit fun2(scores, groups) # Takes ~1.2 mins to run

10.1 s ± 1.32 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Depending on how complicated the "more work done after the fact" is, you might be better of just using the non-numba version. Numba can get a little crazy if you're trying something too complicated (e.g. globals, lists of list, inconsistent types, blah...)